# The best way to get child's node data with random key in firebase?

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is one-to-many relationship: An author has many books

```
authors:
    randomAuthorId1:
        authorId: 
        authorName:
    randomAuthorId2:
        authorID: 
        authorName:
books:
    randomAuthorId1:
        randomBookId1:
            bookId:
            bookName:
        randomBookId2:
            bookId:
            bookName:
    randomAuthorId2:
        randomBookId3:
            bookId:
            bookName:
```

In my case, I **don't have** "randomAuthorId1", but I have "randomBookId2", this is my code to get the value of randomBookId2's node:

```
DatabaseReference bookRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("books");
bookRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (data.hasChild("randomBookId2")) {
                Book book = data.child("randomBookId2").getValue(Book.class);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

So, It has to loop through all children to get randomBookId2's node. Is there a better way?
Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using Query but use query you need to update your Books DB like following the.
books:

```
randomAuthorId1:  
   randomBookId1:
        bookId:  
        randomBookId:randomBookId1
        bookName:
   randomBookId2:
        bookId:
        randomBookId:randomBookId2
        bookName:
randomAuthorId2:
    randomBookId3:
        bookId:
        randomBookId:randomBookId3
        bookName:
```

Now after that you can fire query like bellow

```
Query queryToGetData = databaseReference.child("books")
        .orderByChild("randomBookId").equalTo("randomBookId2");
queryToGetData.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    // TODO: 
    // ...
});
```

It will help you.

Comment: I called `.orderByChild("randomBookId")`, 
Instead of looking for _randomBookId_ of **randomBookId1** node or **randomBookId2** node, it looks for _randomBookId_ of **randomAuthorId1** node and **randomAuthorId2** node.

Comment: I could not understand your comment, Can you please explain more.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.

This method `databaseReference.child("books") .orderByChild("randomBookId")` 
is sorted with a value of `null` because `randomAuthorId1` or `randomAuthorId2` does not have the child key `randomBookId`

Comment: Please replace  .orderByChild("randomBookId") to .orderByChild("bookId") or else update your DB structure which I say in my answer.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. It did not work. If I'm in `databaseReference.child("books")`, calling the method  `.orderByChild("bookId")`, and then that method  is sorted with a value of `null`. Because `bookId` is the grandchild of `books`, i cannot get the value of grandchild by calling method `orderByChild()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168846/discussion-between-huy-tran-and-dhaval-solanki).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a need to call hasChild in eventlistener if you know child name of which value you want to get.Instead of it just refer specific child and put it in try catch. So, if child not found then you can catch exception and perform actions as you want.

**Sample Code:**

```
try
{
    DatabaseReference bookRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("books").child("randomBookId2");
    //add valueevent listener for this reference...
}catch(Exception e){
    //Child not found...perform action according this.
}
```

Comment: You cannot connect direct sub child connecting without parent-child.

Comment: Dhaval Solanki's answer is right. Connecting without parent-child always return null value when calling dataSnapshot.getValue()